# Spark Structured Streaming failing with out of memory of executors in Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, minio

I am running a spark structured streaming job , reading from object store bucket , doing some transformations and filtering , calling groupby and aggregation . Post that writing into object store in csv format.

```
maxFilesPerTrigger = 200
lookback_window = "24 hours"
sliding_interval = "1 hour"
watermark = "1 hour"
output_mode = "update"

df = spark\
    .readStream\
    .format(file_type)\
    .schema(schema)\
    .option("latestFirst", latest_first)\
    .option("maxFileAge", maxFileAge)\
    .option("header", header)\
    .option("timestampFormat", timestampFormat)\
    .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", maxFilesPerTrigger)\
    .load(f"{path}/*.{file_type}")

df = df.filter()
df = df.withcolumn()  .. 20 odd features
df = df.withWatermark()
df= df.groupby(x).agg() 22 features in aggregation.


def foreach_function(agg_df, batch_no):
    global write_minio_path

    t0 = time.time()
    logger.info(f"Writing batch -{batch_no} to {write_minio_path}")
    agg_df.write.mode("append").parquet(write_minio_path)
    logger.info(f"Batch - {batch_no} Time taken  ::{time.time() - t0}")

logger.info("Calling Foreach Batch Function")
query = df.writeStream.foreachBatch(foreach_function).option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path).outputMode(output_mode).start().awaitTermination()
```

**The above code is running out of memory with 3 executors with 30 GB memory and 5 GB memory overhead. The driver is having 10 GB memory with 1 GB overhead.

```
23/09/20 14:09:43 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 4 on IP: The executor with id 4 exited with exit code 52(JVM OOM).



The API gave the following container statuses:


         container name: spark-kubernetes-executor
         container image: spark:3.3.0
         container state: terminated
         container started at: 2023-09-20T14:01:46Z
         container finished at: 2023-09-20T14:09:41Z
         exit code: 52
         termination reason: Error

23/09/20 14:09:49 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job 757c5b44-f7c9-436a-874b-295370b1ab97. org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 87 (start at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException
```

> We are using aws-sdk-java-1.11.0 and hadoop-aws-3.3.0. Do we have any
> thread leaks in these jars which can result in OOM ?
>
> We checked the heapdump of the executor and got state as the biggest
> object in memory. How to calculate the state size required to be
> stored in executor memory ?

Please help me with debugging this.**

Comment: Did you check files in the storage? Average is ok but if one file is significant outlier (e.g. 50g) then it cause problem. Does it fail after multiple batches or immediately?

Comment: Its fails after multiple batches and have no outliers.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. I've never worked with windows/watermarks, probably these cause Spark to accumulate some data across micro-batches.

Comment: Yeah that's called state :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, from my experience

1. `maxFilesPerTrigger` is less predictable than `maxBytesPerTrigger`
2. Even with `maxFilesPerTrigger`, probably 200 files are too much for 3 executors. I would target approximate micro-batch size (either files or bytes based) to be less than half of `sum(executor_memory)/2`. In your case it should be <= 45G. If 200 files exceed that number, then problems are likely.

---

Unrelated note - why do you use `foreachBatch`?

In your case it could be simplified to smth like

```
 df.writeStream.start(
   path=write_minio_path, 
   outputMode="append", 
   format="parquet",
   checkpointLocation=checkpoint_path
 ).awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Hello Alexander, 200 files is set considering the file size which is on an average 1 MB for us. Do you still think it's more?  Also does foreachbatch cause any performance issues? I have a custom function which I want to add later

Comment: No, foreachBatch is fine.